# Calculate Percentage Downloaded and Time Remaining for in OTHER application

Tags: android, http, networking, ftp, download

I want to do the following in Android.
I want to find out the Percentage downloaded and time remaining for tasks being carried out in other applications in MY APK.

For eg, the tasks could be Http File download, FTP Upload/Download,

Youtube Streaming, Email download.

Is it possible to retrieve this information in my application even though the download/upload is being carried in other application? Can anyone please tell me which classes I can use to achieve this.

Thanks & Regards,

Yuvi

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, unless the other apps in question are providing some method for you to get this data. And AFAIK, no app provides such a feature.

On a rooted device you could perhaps monitor incoming network data and see which app it's going to and estimate the progress, but I doubt this could be turned into a proper app.