# calculating the percentage downloaded and time remaining while downloading a file on android

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar, download

I am having an android application that download songs from server to device. I am showing a progress dialog for this . I need to show the downloaded size , remaining size , 
elapsed time and time remaining to the user

How do I get these things from the application in Android?

Any pointers will be most useful.

Regards
Renjith

Comment: this is exactly what 1AsyncTask` is all about.

you should override the `onProgress` and use a `ProgressDialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use async task and override onProgressUpdate()

```
 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
     Log.i("Value", values[0].toString());
     count++;
     progressBar.setProgress(count);
 }
```

Take a look at this link. [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog). The answer in the link should help you.

[Calculate Percentage Downloaded and Time Remaining for in OTHER application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927853/calculate-percentage-downloaded-and-time-remaining-for-in-other-application).
[What's the best way to calculate remaining download time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798800/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-remaining-download-time)

Comment: Thanks for the update . By the i need to add elapsed time and time remaining depending on the bandwidth

Comment: Updated the answer. Have look at the links.